# Targetting specific appended divs using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I have set up a page which lets you enter information about your child. You can add another form and take away another form for the amount of children you wish to enter information about.

However my problem is that I have a button which you can tick and it will hide certain forms and change certain labels. I do this using jQuery. However when I click the button it does it for all the different child information sections and not just the child information section in which I click.

I have tried many ways to do this by using `.parent()` `.parents()` `.children()` `.siblings()` `.find()`. I have also tried targetting the divs and using `this`. However none of this works.

The problem is that I append another set of forms every time someone clicks "add child". But all the id's and classes stay the same. I think the problem is because I have the same ID's but then I have tried ways to make unique id's every time it is appended by using a variable which adds a number new number to the ID depending on how many forms there are. This didn't work and I got really confused.

Is there a way which I can target the form in which they click the button in so it only makes changes to that form?

Here is my jQuery which I am using:

```
 $j = $.noConflict();
    var id_count = 0;
    var id_sub = 1;
    var htmlcode = "<div class='fieldset fieldsetAdditional' > <h2 class='legend'>Child Information</h2><span id='removechild' class='btn-removechild' style='float:right;'><div class='removeChildButton'><i class='icon-white icon-sub'></i></div><p>Remove Child</p></span> <ul class='form-lists form-list'><li class='born'> <div class='full-tbl'> <div class='born-field dob-field'> <input class='checkbox check-input hidden' name='is_born' id='born' type='checkbox'> <label class='check' for='born'>Is Your Child Born Yet?</label> </div></div></li><li class='childname'> <div class='childname-field'> <label for='childname'> Your Child's Name </label> <div class='input-box'> <input type='text' id='childname' title='First Name' maxlength='225' class='input-text'> </div></div></li><li class='gender'> <div class='gender-field'> <label for='gender' class='required'> <em>*</em> Your Child's Gender </label> <div class='input-box'> <select name='gender' class='validate-select input-select' title='gender'> <option disabled='disabled' selected='selected'>Select an option</option> <option>Boy</option> <option>Girl</option> </select> </div></div></li><li class='dob'> <div class='dob-fields'> <label for='dob' class='required'> <em>*</em> Date Of Birth </label><br/> <div class='dob-month input-box dob-field'> <select id='dob-month' name='month' class='validate-select input-select' title='month'> <option disabled='disabled' selected='selected'>Select an option</option> <option value='01'>January</option> <option value='02'>February</option> <option value='03'>March</option> <option value='04'>April</option> <option value='05'>May</option> <option value='06'>June</option> <option value='07'>July</option> <option value='08'>August</option> <option value='09'>September</option> <option value='10'>October</option> <option value='11'>November</option> <option value='12'>December</option> </select> </div><div class='dob-date input-box dob-field'> <input type='text' id='dob-date' title='date' maxlength='2' class='input-text'> </div><div class='dob-year input-box dob-field'> <input type='text' id='dob-year' title='year' maxlength='4' class='input-text'> </div></div></li></ul> </div>";
    $j(".btn-addchild").click(function() {
      $j(".child-info-content").append(htmlcode);
      id_count++;
      //        alert(id_count);
    });
    $j(".child-info-content").on('click', '#removechild', function() {
      $j(this).parents('.fieldsetAdditional').slideUp("normal", function() {
        $j(this).parents('.fieldsetAdditional').remove();
      });
      id_count = id_count - id_sub;
      //        alert(id_count);
    });
    $j('.born').on("click", ".check-input", function() {
      if (this.checked) {
        $j('.childname-field').hide();
        $j('.gender-field label').text("Your Child's Predicted Gender").append("<em>*</em>");
        $j('.input-select').append("<option class='optional'>Unknown</option>");
        $j('.dob-fields label').text("Due Date").append("<em>*</em>");
      } else {
        $j('.childname-field').show();
        $j('.gender-field label').text("Your Child's Gender").append("<em>*</em>");
        $j('.input-select .optional').remove();
        $j('.dob-fields label').text("Date Of Birth").append("<em>*</em>");
      }
    });
    $j(".fieldsetAdditional").click(function() {
      alert("test");
    });
```

I am sorry if this is a really simple or stupid question, I am still learning. I have also looked at a lot of other posts on here to try and find my answer but I can not find a solution or the solution doesn't work for me. I hope you can help me and thank you in advance! I hope this all makes sense as well.

Here is my JSFiddle with all the code for it (apart from some of the styles)(https://jsfiddle.net/benEdpa/0sLad9t5/4/)

Comment: I would suggest you to create `id's` dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So many issues, so little time :)

### 1. Use relative selection:

Get the closest UL to the clicked option and use scoped selectors. These are the same as doing `$formlists.find('.childname-field')` etc

e.g.

```
var $formlists = $(this).closest('.form-lists');
if (this.checked) {
    $j('.childname-field',$formlists).hide();
    $j('.gender-field label',$formlists).text("Your Child's Predicted Gender").append("<em>*</em>");
    $j('.input-select',$formlists).append("<option class='optional'>Unknown</option>");
    $j('.dob-fields label',$formlists).text("Due Date").append("<em>*</em>");
} else {
    $j('.childname-field',$formlists).show();
    $j('.gender-field label',$formlists).text("Your Child's Gender").append("<em>*</em>");
    $j('.input-select .optional',$formlists).remove();
    $j('.dob-fields label',$formlists).text("Date Of Birth").append("<em>*</em>");
}
```

### 2. Delegate events on a non-changing common ancestor

Your delegated `click` handler is also incorrect. It should target an ancestor that does not change:

```
$j(document).on("click", ".born .check-input",function() {
```

### 3. Don't style checkboxes that way

You also have some styling that causes the first checkbox to appear checked when another checkbox is ticked! You need to remove that too.

### 4. You can't duplicate IDs

Duplicate IDs are invalid. A browser will only match the first entry as they store them in a fast lookup with only one element per key value. Change your field to use `name` and/or `class`.